# Why isn't my enqueuing working properly?

Tags: uploads, wp-enqueue-style

I followed [this guide](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166185/what-is-the-correct-way-to-enqueue-multiple-css-files-in-wp) to try to enqueue multiple stylesheets in order to get this [file picker](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput) to work in Wordpress. However, when I am getting an error that says `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in /home/effilxhy/public_html/WP/wp-content/themes/blankslate-child/av_question-form.php on line 2`. What am I missing here?

**functions.php**

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php



function namespace_theme_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fileinput',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/fileinput.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fileinput.min',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/fileinput.min.css', array(), null, 'all' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'namespace_theme_stylesheets' );



?>
```

**Names of files in WP folder**

```
fileinput.css
fileinput.min.css
style.css
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the folder that your css is in, so it might look like this if your styles were in 'css':

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
```

Comment: Theyre all just in public_html/WP/wp-content/themes/blankslate-child. Wait so does this mean all 3 lines need to have 'parent-style' at the beginning?

Comment: Also, do I even need to have multiple stylesheets? Can't I just put all the code into my style.css file? Or might that negatively affect others pages?

Comment: You can place them all in one file. That 'parent-style' part can be anything.